# Ember.js get compound data for each item

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to build the following view with Ember.js:

```
Users: (x in total)

* User 1: y Posts
* User 2: z Posts
```

I've created a [`itemController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) that is responsible for getting the number of posts of each user.

```
App.IndexItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  postCount: function() {
    var posts = this.get('content').get('posts');
    return posts.get('length');
  }.property()
});
```

Full code on [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nalor/2/edit).

Somehow I always get 0 posts for each user, I guess that is because the relationship is not resolved correctly at `this.get('content').get('posts')`. What would be the right way to do this? Or am I going a completely wrong way?

*Bonus question*: What can I pass to the `property()` and should I pass something to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the dependent keys of your computed property, in your case `content.posts.length`. So the `postCount` knows when need to be updated.

```
App.IndexItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  postCount: function() {    
    var posts = this.get('content').get('posts');
    return posts.get('length');
  }.property('content.posts.length')
});
```

Now your computed property is correct, but no data is loaded, this happen because there isn't posts associated with your users, no in the `user -> post` direction. So you need to add it in the fixture:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jon',
    nick: 'Jonny',
    posts: [1]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Foo',
    nick: 'Bar',
    posts: [2]
  }
];
```

After this an error is raised `` Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'posts' relationship on '<App.User:ember280:1>' but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (`DS.hasMany({ async: true })`) ``.
Ember data identified that you have an async relationship, and warns you to setup the property with `async: true`

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  nick: DS.attr('string'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post', { async: true })
});
```

This your updated [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dihevixo/1/edit)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Does that mean that the `posts` property contains the IDs of all the posts that the user has created?

Comment: You are welcome. If you have a user instance with id equal 1, `user.get('posts')` will fetch the posts associated to his user, following the above example, it will retrieve an array with the post of id 1. Keep in mind that because we are using `async: true` the return of `user.get('posts')`, isn't the post itself but a promise. So you need to use `user.get('posts').then(function(posts) { posts[0] /* the post instance */ })`

Comment: Off course you just need to interact with the prommise, if you want to load the posts inside of a controller, route etc. Inside of a template it's ok to just reference the object using paths, and ember will be smart enough to handle the async code

Comment: Thanks again! Just one short follow up question: When accessing the actual post form a promise with the `.then(function(posts)) { getting my data }`, is there a way to return the post data back to the outer scope? `var result = this.get('posts').then(function(posts){return post[0]})` does not seem to work!

Comment: This will not work, because the result will be a promise not the post instance. And even if you assign the resolved post to an outer scope, will not work because it's async

Comment: You can put your logic inside of the promise callback though

Comment: Hey thanks for your continued effort! Really appreciated it. Could you maybe create a JSBin which shows how one could do this? Currently trying to get some data in a controller which is need for manipulation, yet as no relationship to the data passed in the router.